# Can we change the name field value in the formBuilder?

Tags: symfony

All of my question are in the subject :)
It's possible de customize the attribute "name" of a field in the formBuilder ?

If this is possible, can you describe the process for make this ?

Thank you for your reply in advance

Answer (score 5):

You can change "name" attribute with Twig code:

```
{{ form_row(form.myfield, {'full_name':'myname'}) }}
```

You need to use "full_name" because "name" only changes the "title" attribute.

But I think that Symfony Forms uses the name to bind the form fields to the model, and if you change could have problems.

Comment: WORKS LIKE A CHARM! Thank you very much. Exactly what i needed and saved my life, thank you again! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define field label by additional parameter.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', 'text')
        ->add('dueDate', 'date', array('label' => 'Dday'))
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Task')) 
        ->getForm();                 //^
                                     //|by using 3rd parameter 'options' 
                                     //|you can change 'name' of the field
```

Comment: not a label, datatag name <input name="here">

Thank you for your answer Anton Dorozhko

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is my formBuilder class for this

```
$builder
    ->add('type', 'choice', [
        'choices' => [
            '1',
            '2',
            '3'
        ],
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
    ])
;
```

I try to describe better my problem

actually, i have this html code

```
<div class="control-group control-filter">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox-orange">Foo
    </label>
</div>
<div class="control-group control-filter">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox-orange">Foo
    </label>
</div>
<div class="control-group control-filter">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox-orange">Foo
    </label>
</div>
```

But now, i need to convert this code into the formBuilder, i use the choice type and i need to group by name all checkbox of this choice and make a custom class on all input element of these, can i do this ?